# Behaviour changes in math mode when macro is defined dynamically

Tags: math-mode, macros, expansion

Why is my third `O` bigger than the first two ones?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% defining a plain macro
\def\macro{\text{O}}

% defining it dynamically
\foreach \mname/\cmd in {%
    dynmacro/\text{O},%
    } {%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\mname\endcsname{\cmd}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    2^{\text{O}} \times % okay
    2^{\macro} \times   % okay
    2^{\dynmacro}       % this one yields a weird result
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I correct my dynamic macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ask `\show\dynmacro` after `\begin{document}` you’ll be answered

```
> \dynmacro=macro:
->\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \hbox {O}.
```

which is nothing you’d like, isn't it? The problem is `\xdef`. You're even lucky that something meaningful happens. With `\textbf` instead of `\text` you’d get several errors. You need just one step of expansion.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% defining a plain macro
\def\macro{\text{O}}

% defining it dynamically
\foreach \mname/\cmd in {%
    dynmacro/\text{O},%
    } {%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname\mname\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\cmd}%
}

\begin{document}

\show\dynmacro

\begin{equation}
    2^{\text{O}} \times % okay
    2^{\macro} \times   % okay
    2^{\dynmacro}       % this one yields a weird result
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The console now will report

```
> \dynmacro=macro:
->\text {O}.
```

**Important note:** `\text` is not the best for this, it should probably be `\mathrm`.

---

A different implementation: `\dyndef` wants three arguments

1. the input form (optional, default `#1=#2`)
2. the definition to perform
3. the list of things to define

Here are a couple of examples.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dyndef}{O{##1=##2}mm}
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \__iagolito_dyndef_aux:w #1 \q_stop { #2 }
  \clist_map_function:nN { #3 } \iagolito_dyndef:n
 }
\cs_new:Nn \iagolito_dyndef:n { \__iagolito_dyndef_aux:w #1 \q_stop }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% defining it dynamically
\dyndef{\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}{
    dynmacro=\text{O},
    dynmacroA=\mathbf{0},
}

\dyndef[#1/#2/#3]{\newcommand#1{#2-#3}}{
  \foo/A/B,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
2^{\text{O}} \times 2^{\dynmacro} + 2^{\dynmacroA}+(\foo)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the first example uses the default `dynmacro=\text{O}`; for the second example, the specification of the argument is `#1/#2/#3`; the same placeholders are used in the first mandatory argument.

Comment: Beat me by a few minutes, I see.  I will delete my duplicative answer.

Comment: Next question would be why `\text`?

Comment: @daleif I added a note

Comment: I would propose the first argument to be optional with `#1=#2` as a default which seems more usual. The fact that he used `/` in the question is because he was using `\foreach`.

Comment: @Manuel I concur.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for this clear explanation and this neat `\dyndef` alternative, much more comfortable :)

Comment: @egreg Wops, wait. I get a `Parameters need to be numbered consecutively` error while trying to compile your last example (l.19). What's wrong?

Comment: @egreg Got it fixed somehow with `\NewDocumentCommand{\dyndef}{O{#1=#2}mm}`, instead of `##1=##2` :)

Comment: @iago-lito Are you sure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution? The fact that you “fixed” it by changing `##` into `#` tells me you haven't.

Comment: @egreg Wop, maybe not. Debian has old repos you know :P I won't edit your answer for that :)

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that `\xdef` completely expands its argument, and this adds an `\unhbox\voidb@x` to your `\dynmacro`. Using `etoolbox`'s `\expandonce` you can make the `\cmd` expand once only (and using `\csxdef` to make it simpler):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% defining a plain macro
\def\macro{\text{O}}

% defining it dynamically
\foreach \mname/\cmd in {%
    dynmacro/\text{O},%
    } {%
    \csxdef{\mname}{\expandonce\cmd}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    2^{\text{O}} \times % okay
    2^{\macro} \times   % okay
    2^{\dynmacro}       % okay :)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting as well, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop not encapsulating items in macros

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xinttools}

% defining a plain macro
\def\macro{\text{O}}

\makeatletter % for LaTeX's \@namedef
% defining it dynamically
\xintForpair #1#2 in {%
  (dynmacro, \text{O})%
  % add more comma-separated "pairs" if needed
  % (no ending comma, though, only to separate pairs)
}\do
{%
    \@namedef{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    2^{\text{O}} \times % okay
    2^{\macro} \times   % okay
    2^{\dynmacro}        % this one is also okay
\end{equation}

% \showoutput
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice alternative way to define dynamical macros as well. Cheers :)