# Pairing items from two comma-separated lists into a single list

Tags: lists, comma-separated-list

How to pair items from two comma-separated lists (assuming they have the same length) in another list?

I did my best looking for the answer before asking… so I do hope this is not a duplicate!

For example, given to lists
`\def\a{1,2,3,4,5}`
and
`\def\b{a,b,c,d,e}`
I want to define `\parlists` such that
`\def\c{\pairlists[=]{\a}{\b}}`
will define
`\c as {1=a,2=b,3=c,4=d,5=e}`.

I'm no TeX expert at all but, still, I had partial success: it works when the lists are given as parameters, but not when the lists are stored in the commands `\a` and `\b`.  See my attempt below…  Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter
\def\@pairitems[#1]#2,#3\@nil#4,#5\@nil{%
% [#1][#2,#3][#4,#5]%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}%
      {#2#1#4}%
      {\PackageError{example}{Lists are not the same size}}%
  }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}%
      {\PackageError{example}{Lists are not the same size}}%
      {#2#1#4, \@pairitems[#1]#3\@nil#5\@nil}%
  }%
}
\def\pairitems[#1]#2#3{\@pairitems[#1]#2,\@nil#3,\@nil}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\def\a{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\b{a,b,c,d,e}
\def\x{\pairitems[=]{1,2,3,4,5}{a,b,c,d,e}}
\def\y{\pairitems[=]{\a}{\b}}

\noindent
x: \x\\
y: \y\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `\edef\y{\noexpand\pairitems[=]{\a}{\b}}` then you get the same output in the second line.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554334/map-arbitrary-operation-on-zipped-iteration-over-two-comma-separated-lists/554381#554381

Comment: `minimal` class is for testing package loading dependencies. It defines almost zero commands/settings. For MWEs, use standard classes like `book`, `article`, etc.

Comment: beware using `\def`  all three of `\a` `\b` and `\c` are core latex commands defined in the format and this over-writes all three with no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution using LaTeX3 approach. It is worth noticing that LaTeX is a macro language. You can use the `\meaning` to show the definition of a command. When you define `\def\x{\pairitems{\a}{\b}}`, then `\x` is `\pairitems{\a}{\b}`, literally, instead the value of `\pairitems{\a}{\b}`. If you wish `\x` to contain the value of `\pairitems{\a}{\b}`, some special treatment needs to be done.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist
\clist_new:N \l_doc_tmpb_clist
\seq_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_seq

\msg_new:nnn {doc} {difflen} {two~comma~separated~lists~have~different~length}


\cs_set:Npn \doc_pair_items:nnn #1#2#3 {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \clist_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpb_clist {#3}
    \seq_clear:N \l_doc_tmpa_seq
    
    \int_compare:nNnF {\clist_count:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist} = {\clist_count:N \l_doc_tmpb_clist} {
        \msg_error:nn {doc} {difflen}
    }
    
    \int_step_inline:nn {\clist_count:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist} {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_seq {
            \clist_item:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {##1}
            #1
            \clist_item:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {##1}
        }
    }
    
    \seq_use:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_seq {,}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \doc_pair_items:nnn {nxx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \doc_pair_items:nnn {noo}

\newcommand{\pairitems}[3][=]{
    \doc_pair_items:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
}

\newcommand{\pairitemso}[3][=]{
    \doc_pair_items:noo {#1} {#2} {#3}
}

\newcommand{\pairitemsx}[3][=]{
    \doc_pair_items:nxx {#1} {#2} {#3}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\par\pairitems{1,2,3,4,5}{a,b,c,d,e}
\par\pairitems[+]{1,2,3,4,5}{a,b,c,d,e}

\def\a{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\b{a,b,c,d,e}
\par\pairitems{\a}{\b}
\par\pairitemso{\a}{\b}

\def\x{\pairitemso{\a}{\b}}
\par\meaning\x
\edef\x{\noexpand\pairitemso{\a}{\b}}
\par\meaning\x

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This produces terminal output

```
> \zc=macro:
->1=a, 2=b, 3=c, 4=d, 5=e.
```

and typeset

[image]

Note the use of `\unexpanded` so that terms in the list should be protected from expansion, even though edef is used to save the result.  I changed the calling order making the command define the specified token `\zc`

```
\documentclass{article}

% don't break latex accent support by redefining \a \b or \c which are
% all core latex commands....

\def\za{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\zb{a,b,c,d,e}

\newcommand\pairlists[4][=]{%
 \edef#2{%
 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\xpairlists
 \expandafter#3\expandafter,\expandafter\relax#4,\relax#1\zstop
 }}

\def\xpairlists#1,#2\relax#3,#4\relax#5\zstop{%
   \unexpanded{#1#5#3}%
   \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$%
     \expandafter\gobblezstop
   \fi
   , \xpairlists#2\relax#4\relax#5\zstop}

\def\gobblezstop#1\zstop{}

\pairlists[=]{\zc}{\za}{\zb}

\show\zc

\begin{document}
\zc
\end{document}
```

Comment: this does assume the items are single tokens, that could be fixed if it's an issue.

Comment: @UlrichDiez you could have left it (it was of course correct, I'd upvoted it:-)

Comment: David, you're the closest I know to a magician.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some `\expandafter`-and-argument-exchanging-trickery in order to have the macros holding the lists of comma separated items expanded before `\pairitems` gets carried out.

In case you don't like to use `\edef` (which would trigger expansion of the comma-list's comma-separated items themselves, too), you can (ab?)use `\romannumeral` which triggers expansion until having gathered a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity and in case that TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity denotes a non-positive value silently just gobbles the tokens forming that TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

%===================[adjust margins/layout for the example]====================
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\advance\textwidth-2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.5cm
\footskip=.5\topmargin
{\normalfont\global\advance\footskip.5\ht\strutbox}%
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\pagestyle{plain}
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=0ex 
\topsep=0ex
\partopsep=0ex
%==================[eof margin-adjustments]====================================

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \ifcat Y\detokenize{#1}Y%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\@ifdefinable\@pairitems{%
  \long\def\@pairitems#1#2,#3\@nil#4,#5\@nil#6{%
    \CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
      \CheckWhetherNull{#5}%
        {\z@#6#2#1#4}%
        {\z@\PackageError{example}{Lists are not the same size}}%
    }{%
      \CheckWhetherNull{#5}%
        {\z@\PackageError{example}{Lists are not the same size}}%
        {\@pairitems{#1}#3\@nil#5\@nil{#6#2#1#4,}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\pairitems[3]{\romannumeral\@pairitems{#1}#2,\@nil#3,\@nil{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newcommand*\one{1}
\newcommand*\two{2}
\newcommand*\three{3}
\newcommand*\four{4}
\newcommand*\five{5}
\newcommand*\MYa{a}
\newcommand*\MYb{b}
\newcommand*\MYc{c}
\newcommand*\MYd{d}
\newcommand*\MYe{e}

\newcommand*\ListA{\one,\two,\three,\four,\five}
\newcommand*\ListB{\MYa,\MYb,\MYc,\MYd,\MYe}
\newcommand*\PairedU{\pairitems{=}{\one,\two,\three,\four,\five}{\MYa,\MYb,\MYc,\MYd,\MYe}}
\newcommand*\PairedV{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListB}}{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListA}}{\pairitems{=}}}}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter\PairedW\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\pairitems{=}{\one,\two,\three,\four,\five}{\MYa,\MYb,\MYc,\MYd,\MYe}%
}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\expandafter\PairedX\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListB}}{%
    \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListA}}{%
      \Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\pairitems{=}%
    }%
  }%
}

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\PairedY{%
  \edef\PairedY{\pairitems{=}{\one,\two,\three,\four,\five}{\MYa,\MYb,\MYc,\MYd,\MYe}}%
}%

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\PairedZ{%
  \edef\PairedZ{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListB}}{\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\expandafter{\ListA}}{\pairitems{=}}}}%
}%

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedU:\\\meaning\PairedU}\\$\to$\PairedU\bigskip

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedV:\\\meaning\PairedV}\\$\to$\PairedV\bigskip

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedW:\\\meaning\PairedW}\\$\to$\PairedW\bigskip

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedX:\\\meaning\PairedX}\\$\to$\PairedX\bigskip

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedY:\\\meaning\PairedY}\\$\to$\PairedY\bigskip

\noindent{\ttfamily \string\PairedZ:\\\meaning\PairedZ}\\$\to$\PairedZ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course all this does not take the case of two empty lists into account.
Also there is no treatment of space-tokens surrounding comma-separated list items.
Also there is no special treatment of blank/empty list items.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `\def\x{\pairlists...}` (and using `\def` in documents is not really recommended anyway).

Here's an implementation in `expl3`. The command `\mergelists` has four arguments:

1. `#1` (optional, default `=`) what to put in the middle of the items
2. `#2` is the name for the new list
3. `#3` is the first list to merge, either with a symbolic name or explicit
4. `#4` is the second list to merge, either with a symbolic name or explicit

If the lists don't match by number of items, an error is raised.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mergelists}{O{=}mmm}
 {
  \joaolourenco_mergelists:Nnnn #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__joaolourenco_first_seq
\seq_new:N \l__joaolourenco_second_seq
\clist_new:N \l__joaolourenco_temp_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joaolourenco_mergelists:Nnnn
 {
  % #1 = name for the merged list
  % #2 = first list
  % #3 = second list
  % #4 = separator

  % check whether #2 is a symbolic name and fill in the sequence
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { #2 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N #2 }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l__joaolourenco_first_seq #2
   }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__joaolourenco_first_seq { #2 }
   }
  % check whether #3 is a symbolic name and fill in the sequence
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { #3 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N #3 }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l__joaolourenco_second_seq #3
   }
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__joaolourenco_second_seq { #3 }
   }

  % check whether the lists have the same number of elements
  \int_compare:nTF
   {
    \seq_count:N \l__joaolourenco_first_seq = \seq_count:N \l__joaolourenco_second_seq 
   }
   {% true, do the real job
    \__joao_lourenco_mergelists:Nn #1 { #4 }
   }
   {% false
    \PackageError{example}{Lists~are~not~the~same~size}{Your~lists~have~different~size}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__joao_lourenco_mergelists:Nn
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__joaolourenco_temp_clist
  \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l__joaolourenco_first_seq }
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nx \l__joaolourenco_temp_clist
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \l__joaolourenco_first_seq { ##1 }
      #2
      \seq_item:Nn \l__joaolourenco_second_seq { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \clist_clear_new:N #1
  \clist_set_eq:NN #1 \l__joaolourenco_temp_clist
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\lista{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\listb{a,b,c,d,e}

\mergelists{\listx}{\lista}{\listb}

\texttt{\meaning\listx}

\mergelists[+]{\listy}{\lista}{a,b,c,d,e}

\texttt{\meaning\listy}

\mergelists{\listz}{1,2,3,4}{a,b,c,d}

\texttt{\meaning\listz}

\mergelists{\listerror}{1,2,3}{a,b}

\end{document}
```

The output on the console will be

```
! Package example Error: Lists are not the same size.

See the example package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.87 \mergelists{\listerror}{1,2,3}{a,b}

? h
Your lists have different size
```

The PDF file will have

[image]

With `\bool_lazy_and:nnTF` we check that the argument is a single token which is a control sequence and, in this case, we assume it is the symbolic name for a list. Otherwise, the entire argument is the list.

The lists are converted to sequences; the number of items in each is compared. If they don't match, an error is raised. Otherwise, a clist is built from the items, with the separator in between.

Finally, the chosen control is assigned the value of the constructed clist.

Answer (score 1):

I made the syntax a little different, if that works for the OP.  Here, one executes `\makepairlist[=]{\a}{\b}` to create the desired pair list in a macro `\thepairlist`. In the MWE, I show that the detokenized macro is already expanded to the desired list.

If desired, one could follow up with `\edef\c{\thepairlist}` or, even better, `\let\c\thepairlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\makepairlist[3][:]{%
  \readlist\ListA{#2}%
  \readlist\ListB{#3}%
  \def\thepairlist{}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\ListA[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\relax\else\edef\thepairlist{\thepairlist,}\fi
    \edef\thepairlist{\thepairlist\z#1\ListB[\zcnt]}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\def\a{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\b{a,b,c,d,e}
\makepairlist[=]{\a}{\b}
\thepairlist

\detokenize\expandafter{\thepairlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]